# Last Element in ForEach

Tags: c++, foreach

Does C++ have a pre-built method to identify which element you are on in your foreach loop, or if there is a way to identify if you are on your last element? Or do I have to do it manually with a counter?

Comment: If you need to know the index of each element (or any element), you should just use a for loop instead.

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no such built-in way.  Nor could there be for iterators in general, because iterators aren't required to know that they are "almost" at the end.

Comment: For most iterators it's quite easy: `if (it + 1 == end)`

Answer (score 4):

If you find yourself needing the index your probably better off using a regular for loop

Comment: Darn it. I'm just feeling lazy to re-write my loop! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

If you need the last element, how about using another iterator to store it before you go to the next item in the container?  If you set both to the start and then at the end of you loop before you get the next element (increment or decrement the iterator) , set last iterator to current and then get the next.

Something like this:

```
container current::iterator;
container last::iterator;
current = container.first();
last = current;  // or contianer.first();
while ( current is valid ) 
{
  // do something 
  last = current;
  // get the next item 
  current = container.next(); // or current++; 
                              // depending upon container or 
                              // iterator
}
```

That way you don't have to rewrite your loop, but you do need to check to make sure your container is not empty before this.

Comment: Just indent code four spaces (there is a button for it look for `{}`)