# How can I tell that I'm at the last object in a foreach, in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I was wondering if anyone knows of a library method or function within Qt that will tell you when you've hit the last object in a foreach.

Below I'm rolling on a list of strings and I've made up a fictional method below called "isLast()":

```
foreach( QString a_string, string_list )
{
    if ( a_string.isLast() )   // does something like this exist?
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if anything like "isLast()" exists?

Thanks,
Wes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Last Element in ForEach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729467/last-element-in-foreach)

Comment: If you are interested in the last item of a list a foreach loop may not be the right approach ... what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to know if its rolled through the list and is at the last one.  I want to know if there is a Qt library method that will tell me this.  Please read the question guys.

Comment: Just use an iterator or an index. What you're asking is a bad idea because by their very nature "foreach" implies "I don't care about the order" and "last" implies "is the current one the last in the sequence". If you're using an object's method, it would have to know whether it's the last object or not which would mean it would have to be aware it was in a container. Hence why iterators were invented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not seen an `isLast()`-style function around QT.  Your best bet is probably to mix in a little old-school counter logic:

```
int str_count = 0;
int str_list_last_elem = string_list.size()-1;

foreach(QString a_string, string_list) {
    str_count++;
    if (str_count == str_list_last_elem) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking this is what I'd probably have to do.  I was just hoping maybe some Qt Guru somewhere knew of some ancient dusty old convince method.  Appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 2):

If the strings in `string_list` all have unique values you could do:

```
foreach(QString a_string, string_list) {
    if(a_string == string_list.last()){
        // it's the last string
    }

    ...
}
```

Otherwise you would have to use some sort of counter as @ascentury suggested.